# Лезгинка — коллективное или общее название?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, названия, выбор-варианта

> Лезгинка - коллективное название данное русскими для народных танцев народов Кавказа.

Какое слово лучше использовать в подобных предложениях: *коллективное* название, *общее* название или просто как-то перестроить само предложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Лезгинка](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) — это не только название народного танца, но и музыка такого танца.

Вот как о ней говорится на сайте «Культура.РФ»:

> Лезгинка — это **общее название** для всех быстрых кавказских танцев, которые в культуре разных народов называются по-разному. Лезгинку исполняют под музыку с ритмом в 6/8. Ее принято танцевать во время праздников — календарных, свадеб, дней рождения — и на сцене. Историки и хореографы сходятся во мнении, что точно установить, какой кавказский народ придумал лезгинку, невозможно.
>
> Исследователи полагают, что лезгинка восходит к древним временам, когда кавказские народы совершали обряды перед битвами и охотой — обычно ими были ритуальные танцы. А русское название «лезгинка» танец получил от слова «лезгин», которым до революции ошибочно называли все горские народы Дагестана.

Иногда используются и другие формулировки: *собирательное название, обобщенное название.*

Прилагательное "коллективный" мне представляется не совсем удачным.
Даже если вы захотите его оставить, то лучше написать так ("данное русскими" — это как-то пренебрежительно; "народных" и "народов" — повтор):
*Лезгинка — русское коллективное название народных танцев Кавказа.*

[Интересные факты о лезгинке](https://www.culture.ru/materials/253732/interesnye-fakty-o-lezginke)